# Why is ArcMap not clipping to Polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, clip, arcgis-10.4

I want to cut a polygon layer with many small polygons (green) to the borders of a polygon-layer with only one large polygon (red). I use the standard geoprocessing clip tool in ArcMap 10.4. Why is it not clipping to the borders?

[image]

Comment: Check to make sure your green polygon is topologically valid.

Comment: What are the coordinate systems of your clipping FC, clipped FC and dataset? Are you using any true rather than vertexed curves in your clipping FC?

Comment: Is that screenshot from before you run the Clip tool, or after?

Comment: The coordinate systems (layer properties and data frame) are all the same (EPSG 25833). the screenshot is before AND after I ran the clipping tool - no difference. I expected the overlapping green polygons to be clipped to the dark red line.

Comment: @PolyGeo: how can I find out if I run true rather than vertexed curves in my clipping feature class?

Comment: If they are buffers in a file geodatabase then I think they will contain true curves.  Certainly a single point buffer will.

Comment: mmmhhh... I don't think I have buffers... I exported both FC to shapefiles and tried to clip than - it worked! but not for all my layers I wanted to clip, for some it doesn't work, although I exported them to shapefiles. strange thing...

Comment: I have 2 advices for starters. 1. Repair your geometry. 2.Check if any is Z enabled, some tools would not intersect Z with noZ.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ArcGIS Desktop *Standard or Advanced* you can use the **Construct Polygon** tool or the **Split Polygon** on the **Advanced Editing** toolbar. You select the geometry you want to cut into the base polygon and click the tool. There are minor differences in between the tools but the basic outcome is the same: You have "stamped" the selected polygons into the base polygon.